# Java code hot-replace|reload with JDK's Java Compiler or groovy

Tags: java, groovy, classloader, hotswap

It seems to me that with the JDK's javax.tools.JavaCompiler there should be an easy way to improve developer's productivity by live code-replace (a'la JRebel, but with more generic way). My idea is that I launch my app, edit the Java sources (suppose outside of the IDE) and the running code will refresh itself with the new sources automatically. (no manual compile or any other action should be required on the developer's side).

Does anyone has a working prototype?

My other idea would be to use groovy to reload the Java classes (thus, using Groovy only for development but not for runtime).

ps. I know Eclipse Java debugger has this, but that is suboptimal.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Play! framework, it has that aim.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "we-implement-your-ideas-for-you" service.

Comment: meriton: I'm sorry if it seemed that way, fortunately e.g. Todd thought it was otherwise.

Comment: M Platvoet: good point! I was aware of play but I haven't really though about checking its source code.

Comment: JRebel have invested a lot of time and expertise in solving this solution, why start again from scratch?

Comment: Don: The limited experience I had with JRebel was that it is great for handling large full-blow 'enterprise' project from the IDE and reduce the deployment overhead. Right now I am evaluating alternative methods to do similar thing, without any IDE, just the command line. Yes, the outcome might be to just buy JRebel...

Comment: regarding _"why start again from scratch"_ if JRebel exists... because a license costs 475 USD per year and in my work experience (> 10 years) so far I can' remember any company which has _any_ money invested in tools for their own developers. Bosses of sofware companies don't like to pay this kind of money, it's expected to be all open source and free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a couple ways I've had much success with hot code-replace on the JVM NOT inside of a Grails project.  Both were with Spring:

1)  Use a scripted bean written in Groovy/Ruby/Beanshell with either 'refresh' or 'reload' set in the configuration (can't remember which right now but I can find if necessary) -> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.5/reference/dynamic-language.html

2)  Start out using a Groovlet -> http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets

3)  If you have a Spring bean class, I seem to remember recompiling then having a script take a class file and overwriting on Tomcat with some success a while back.  I think the Spring proxy might make this work but it has been a while since I messed with this.

Good luck!

Comment: #1 seems to be my best choice as part of the infrastructure, and I might use #2 as the pattern to do the classloading. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome!  The attribute for refreshing is 'refresh-check-delay' and the best examples I have found were in the 'Spring in Action' book by Manning.  But the URL I posted appears to cover it as well.